# How to specify a web address to a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a rails application, that I would like to start on boot. Also if I start the server from console like

```
cd <path of the application>
rails s -p 3000
```

I will have to keep the console open, else the application will end as soon as I end the terminal.

Second to access the application I will have to access **localhost:3000**. I would rather like to have access it with a proper name like **localhost/myapp** or just **myapp** in browser.

First, is it possible? How do I do that?

PS: I already have some PHP applications running on Apache. I would not like to mess with the default 80 / 8080 port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hosts` to add

`127.0.0.1    myapp`

Also, start with `rails s -p 80` if you don't want to specify the 3000 port in the browser. This can interfere with an Apache process already listening to the 80 port.

EDIT : To make it work with Apache :

Let the Rails app on the 3000 port and enable `mod proxy` for Apache, in order to `ProxyPass` requests incoming to the `myapp` host.

There is several examples here : httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I was not clear earlier, I do not want to mess with 80 or 8080 as I have some PHP applications already running on Apache

Comment: Indeed, let rails app on the 3000 port and enable the mod proxy for Apache in order to ProxyPass request incoming to the "myapp" host. There is several examples here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Can you add the comment to the answer, for future visitors and so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Done ;) Glad to see that it helped you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pow](http://pow.cx/) for this. Its a zero-config Rack server for Mac OS X.

** Edit **

[Prax](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax) is an alternative for Linux OS

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to edit your hosts file you can also make use of [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me/). Simply access your website with any subdomain like `example.localtest.me:3000` or `www.localtest.me:3000`.