# local Rails with domain name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify a web address to a rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276118/how-to-specify-a-web-address-to-a-rails-application)

I want to boot 2 Rails on my machine. I can do this way:

```
rails s -p 3000
rails s -p 3001
```

And access them through `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001`.

But is there any way to boot them on `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`? I don't really own the domain name `example.com`, and I just want my local programs to access them through this fake domain name instead of localhost.

Comment: I have already answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276118/how-to-specify-a-web-address-to-a-rails-application/13276271#13276271

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Linux (I'm not sure of this in Mac), edit the file **/etc/hosts** with **sudo**, and add two lines:

```
127.0.1.1      foo.example.com
127.0.1.1      bar.example.com
```

If you point your browser to any of them, it should work. Then start the servers of your Rails Apps:

```
rails s 
rails s -p 3001
```

Finally point your browser to:

```
foo.example.com:3000
bar.example.com:3001
```

Comment: awesome it works! im just wondering, is there anyway to remove :3000 so it will work just like foo.example.com ?

Comment: @mpalencia, try `sudo rails server --port=80`

Comment: It's /etc/hosts for MacOS as well